# Socket.io swift client disconnects automatically

Tags: ios, swift, multithreading, socket.io

I am using socket.io swift client in my app (version 13.1.0) Things work fine, but sometimes this scenario occurs: 
Socket gets disconnected (3 out of 10 times). After it gets disconnected it tries and gets connected successfully, but after this it gets disconnected again and this forms an infinite loop of connected - disconnected state. I am searched but didn't get any possible solution. 
My code is very simple. I have created a singleton class and its code is given as follows:

```
class SocketIOManager: NSObject {


    static let sharedInstance = SocketIOManager()
    let manager = SocketManager(socketURL: URL(string: "URL")!, config: [.compress, .log(true), .reconnects(false)])

    override init() {
       super.init()
       let socket = manager.defaultSocket

        socket.on("connect") {data, ack in
           NSLog("*************** SOCKET CONNECTED")
        }
    }

    func establishConnection() {
       let socket = manager.defaultSocket
       socket.connect()
    }
}
```

Other than this I am elegantly disconnecting socket when app goes in background and then connecting it again when app comes in foreground.

**Things I have tried:**

- Tried the configs parameters: forceNew(true/false), reconnects(true/false), forceWebsockets(true/false)
- In order to keep the connection active, I am sending an empty parameter to the server every 10 seconds, so that it knows that the app is in active state.

**My observation:**
I am using Alamofire in the same project and it send requests in background thread. Might be possible that at some point of time both libs start using the same background thread and socket connection breaks.

Is this possible? Correct me if I am wrong in my understanding. 
What should I do to overcome this socket disconnection problem. I am a newbie to iOS so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: How long does it take before you get disconnected? Is the disconnection based on the duration of the connection, the time since the last data exchanged, or after every exchange? What's your server? Is there anything between the client and server (proxy, reverse proxy, load balancer, anti-DDoS, firewall...)?

Comment: There is nothing like load balancer or firewall. Server is in node js and it is using socket.io library for node js. 
Disconnection is totally random. Sometimes it will get disconnected on the splash screen of the app. The other time it will work perfectly for 15 to 20 mins and all calls will be performed successfully. Sometimes it will get disconnected somewhere in between.